# Starting workflows and moving documents

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am trying to create a Workflow in SharePoint designer 2010.

Here are the steps

1. If a document's property field "status" is changed to "pending team review"
       Then an email is sent to the Team
2. If a document's property field "status" is changed to "final", then it is copied to another library (B) and an email is sent to reviewers of this document.
3. If a document's property field "status" is changed to "Final DO NOT CHANGE", then it is copied back to the origional library (A) and deleted from the current and an email is sent to the initiator of the work flow.

I created a workflow in SPD for the first two steps and associated it with Library A. The copy and email functions work fine. However an email is being sent whenever the document is updated.

***How do I start a work flow only when a specific field is changed?***

I tried to create a workflow for step 3, using similar atributes as the first, but it does not work at all, no coping and no email.

***How do I move a document from one library to another, and then back, based on the value of a field?***

Comment: Why do you need to move the document between libraries? why not to use an "Approval Status" column (something like that) and then create different views to show the items as you need.

If you move the document to another library you should need  another WF on that library.

Answer (score 0):

***How do I start a work flow only when a specific field is changed?***

The only way to do this is to handle specific changes, like in a choice field. For example:

```
If CurrentItem:ChoiceField equals Choice1
 //do work
Else If CurrentItem:ChoiceField equals Choice2
 //do work
```

The only other way to handle a specific field change is to use the "Wait for field change" to watch for the change, however your workflow will be always running and waiting for that field to change.

***How do I move a document from one library to another, and then back, based on the value of a field?***

It may be best to use multiple folders if this is a new process/idea. However, you can move a document using the Copy Document action and Delete Item thereafter. However, you are going to have to maintain two workflows. It may be best to figure out how to tackle this scenario a different way.

Comment: Thank you for the input. It is part of our governance that we do not use folders. I have created a second workflow on Library B, used the copy and delete actions, but it does not work. I thought that maybe it was because I was trying to copy it back to a library with a document of the same name.